# Xcode 7.2 successful archives will not show in organizer, but will show in archives folder about derived data folder

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, xcode7, testflight

I am using `Cocoapods 0.39.0` and `Xcode 7.2`, I have a ***project that archives successfully but does not populate in organizer***. When I tested my podfile in a blank project the archive showed up in the `Organizer` just fine.

While trying to troubleshoot this I found that there was an Archives folder above Derived Data. There I actually found all the .xcarchive files of the project that won't show up in the Organizer.

[image: Archive Folder Above Derived Data]

When clicking on the file details, I also noticed that the working Archive had a size (228.3 MB for the test project) but my main project I want working has a size of 0 bytes.

[image: Test Project]
[image: Main Project]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. Searched `Installation Directory` in `Build Settings`
2. Removed `@executable_path/../Frameworks` as the value for Installation Directory
3. Typed the following for the Installation Directory  `$(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)`

Reference: **"Xcode successfully archived my application, but the Archives Organizer does not list my archive" section** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me too, although I'm coding in Objective-C.

Comment: This proved useful to me for an xcode project generated with CMake.

Answer (score 5):

In XCode Project\Targets\Build Settings make sure

Skip Install = NO

for your Archive scheme, if you created one, or Release scheme

Answer (score 5):

In my case (Xcode 8.3.3), the `Installation Directory` was pointing to `/Applications` which seemed correct, so that wasn't the issue. What worked was:
1. restart Xcode
2. Product ➞ Clean
3. delete the whole 'Derived Data' folder (to see where it is: Xcode ➞ Preferences... ➞ Locations ➞ Derived Data)
4. Product ➞ Clean

Comment: Same problem on Xcode 10.2.1. I don't know why this happens, tried everything from revoking/re-creating certificates, re-installing Xcode, using fastlane to generate certificates but nothing worked. Only deleting the `Derived Data` folder resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I created debug build pointing to our QA environment. 
Debug build was just Zero byte. 
As @kareem mention above I figure that release/distributio build are having path as **/Applications**.

I just duplicated for my debug build and bingo !!! 
Yes you can add /Application instead of current value which was '**@executable_path/../Frameworks**'

This way if you archive your debug build, you will have actual archive just like release build

All credit goes to kareem. I just try to enhanced by adding another prespective.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest step that worked for me.

1. Delete folder `Derived Data` (to see where it is: Xcode ➞ Preferences... ➞ Locations ➞ Derived Data)
2. Generate the archive, select the Xcode ➞ Product ➞ Archive
3. Once the process is complete the archive will be displayed in the `Archive` screen of the `Organizer` dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue in Xcode 12.4 then I tried with the method @kareem said.
But after that as well was not resolved.

One of the pod framework in my project is enabled for the App Extension as well. So I removed it from pod and installed using Swift Package Manager.
This resolved my issue.

Afterward I tried another way:
Also I modified the podfile like below and reintal and it worked:

```
target 'ProjectName' 
do 
use_frameworks! 
. . . 
target 'ProjectNameBroadcast' 
do 
inherit! :search_paths 
end 
target 'ProjectNameBroadcastSetupUI' 
do 
inherit! :search_paths 
end 
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
1. Clean
2. Build
```

Worked for me.