# Xcode archive not showing in Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a React Native app I am trying to publish to the App Store.

In XCode `9.4.1` when I go into `Product>Archive` , the project archives successfully, but the `Organizer` window does not open.

Manually opening the `Organizer` view `Window>Organizer` shows the project but there are no archives for the project.

Checking in the default `Archives` directory show the archive was created but is just not showing in the `Organizer`

Some solutions I have tried inlcude

- In `Build Settings` setting `Skip Install` to `No`
- In `Schemes` setting it to `React` and ticking `Shared` for that scheme.
- Confirmed the `Installation Directory` is `/Applications`

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: This works for me, using Xcode 9.2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45925542/757070

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the archive was corrupt. When I opened the archive directory, the latest archive was there. But the organizer was not opening automatically. As it was corrupt.

**Issue** - While debugging, I figured out it was getting currupt due to the addition of one dependency via cocoa pods. I removed that. Then everything was back to normal.

Comment: How did you figured out that it was getting corrupt?

Comment: In the last app release, everything was working fine. We added one dependency in the next release. So tried removing it and archiving again. It worked.