# Xcode builds successfully a corrupted archive, not showing in organizer, as soon as cocoapods installs react-native-mapbox-gl from Podfile

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl-js, xcode12, mapbox-ios, mapbox-ios-maps

The problem [seems not new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575731/xcode-archive-not-showing-in-organizer), [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433818/xcode-7-2-successful-archives-will-not-show-in-organizer-but-will-show-in-archi/45925542#45925542), but the solutions proposed didn't work.
I tried also several other approaches to understand what's going on ([see here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/issues/2674#issuecomment-730866222)).
To replicate, this is the process:

- I have a working iOS App written in Swift.
- I follow the description to integrate this app with Native React [this procedure](https://reactnative.dev/docs/_integration-with-exisiting-apps-swift)
- I add to the package.json the following dependencies, and run `yarn install`:
  `"@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps":"^8.1.0-rc.9",`
  `"prop-types": "^15.6.2",`
- I run `pod install --repo-update` and Archive on Xcode.
  OUTPUT: At this point the organizer displays my Archive.
- I implement a basic view on mapbox following this procedure
- I add to the Podfile requiring `use_framework!`,  [as described here](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/ios/install.md) or after `use_framework!`, no difference in the result after I hit `pod install --repo-update`.
- I hit Archive on Xcode.
  OUTPUT: the archive is generated successfully, but doesn't show up on the organizer. If I try to open it, the archive is corrupted.

If I remove the pod file of mapbox and I Archive the project after hitting `pod install --repo-update`, the archive works and shows up in the organizer. [Here the same description](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/issues/2674#issuecomment-730866222).

The project runs both as debug and release on a real iPhone 8. Mapbox works well. However, it doesn't work on simulator, nor archive. I can leave with the former, but I can't push on App store because of the latter.

I would not give up as Mapbox is very nice and provides lots of features. What could it be?

Answer (score 3):

SOLUTION :

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.9.3
rm Podfile.lock
rm -rf Pods
pod install
```

LAST MESSAGES :

Same here. Impossible to find any solution.

Xcode is building a incomplete archive file. (By incomplete, I mean that in the archive package, some files are missing, like `info.plist`)

If this can help, I'm using MapboxGL too.

Edit :
Found this https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/1097#issuecomment-725689831

Edit 2:
This link was the solution !

Comment: I tried, and I got in another "cul de sac", in my case with YGMacros.h https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651941

Comment: Also in my case info.plist is missing

Comment: I read here and I wonder whether @cocoapods are aware of it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137084/xcode-creating-generic-xcode-archive-instead-of-ios-app-archive

Comment: I found a terrible solution, inspired to the above link 57137084. I have to manually pick from the corrupted archive, which has Mapbox, the files that are missing in the working archive, which has not MapBox. Then I overwrite the Application folder from the corrupted archive, to the working archive. The result is a working archive, which can be uploaded to AppStore and the application works as expected. How can this operation be accomplished automatically from cocoapods? Why doesn't work out of the box?

Answer (score 3):

I got the exact same problem with :

- @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "8.1.0"
- COCOAPODS: 1.10.1
- Xcode 12.4

The archive was corrupted (missing parts like the plist)

The trick for me was to remove the copy dsym build phase of the @react-native-mapbox-gl-mapbox-static pod

This phase was causing build failure with some config and malformed archive with others, I don't really get the crux of the problem but may be it can help some of you...

Comment: you may also try the workaround stated in this issue : https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10385

Comment: this solves my issue thanks so much! i have removed mapbox as my dependency in my react native project and it now archives correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mapbox issue. I had the same issue and instead of downgrading the cocoapods I used [this](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/1097#issuecomment-813057452) solution:

1. Edit your *package.json*, set:

> "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "^8.2.0-beta1",
> 2. Run `yarn install` or `npm install`.
> 3. Put the code into your *ios/Podfile* between `pre_install do |installer|` and `end`:
> $RNMBGL.pre_install(installer)

And between `post_install do |installer|` and `end`:

> ```
> $RNMBGL.post_install(installer)
> ```

3. Run `cd ios && pod install`

After these steps I was able to generate to archive.